# SQL query how to drop table that is in not active in table2

Tags: sql, mariadb

SQL query how to drop table that is in not active in table2

Table2 include columns `server_name` and `active`.

I want to run query if active=0 then get server_name and drop all tables.

`server_name` is yahoo for drop tables outside from table2.

Table1 example (for drop):

```
tablename
google
yahoo
```

Table2 example:

```
server_name,active
google 1
yahoo 0
```

I want to run generally query to drop yahoo table, because yahoo is not active in table2.

So I need to drop table_name: yahoo

I have 1000 tables I want to drop outside from table2.

Which query do I need to run for this ?

Comment: What database server are you using? You need to provide more details on your question.

Comment: I'm using mysql / phpmyadmin. (sql).
My question is simple
How to drop table1,2,3,4,5 from table2 where active=0 and select server_name and delete tables with that server name

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a stored procedure that has a cursor that would loop through all the records in the table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE demo()
BEGIN
DECLARE tablename varchar(100);
DECLARE activeflag tinyint;
DECLARE stm varchar(1000);

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT server_name, active FROM table2

OPEN cur;

read_loop: LOOP
  FETCH cur1 INTO tablename, activeflag

  IF (activeflag < 1)
    SET stm = CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', tablename);
    PREPARE stmt FROM stm;
    EXECUTE stmt;
  END IF;

END LOOP;

CLOSE cur;
END
```

Essentially, the Stored Procedure would iterate through your table, check if that record is active and then prepare a statement to run your DROP TABLE command.

Comment: I'm getting this error:

[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'cur;

read_loop: LOOP
  FETCH cur1 INTO server_name, activeflag

  IF (acti' at line 9

Comment: I though you were using mySQL? Why is there a MariaDB error on the instance?

Comment: I Was thinking i use sql, but is MariaDB as i see.

Once again. i have this servers.sql inside this table is server_name(varchar50) and active (int) columns.
Inside servers.sql are two records google-> active=0 and yahoo active=1. 
In database are two tables called google.sql and yahoo.sql.

I Want to run a script checking from servers.sql checking who is active=0 then drop google.sql table

Comment: I don't have a MariaDB handy at the moment, but pretty much, I am quite sure that you need to construct an stored proc that would iterate through that table where you store the table names and the flag whether it is active or not. Then you store the table name to a variable and then prepare a SQL command to drop the table which was stored in the variable.